# What does the @ character do in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, operators

On the [selectors page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), it says `@` is one of the meta-characters. But what does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *used* to be used in [the attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), but that's no longer the case as of jQuery 1.3+.  From the attribute selector docs:

> **Note:** In jQuery 1.3 `[@attr]` style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the `“@”` symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.

Comment: I wish I had seen this post like an hour ago. So much frustration =(

Answer (score 3):

It was formerly used to grab an attribute, eg `[@href]` but it's no longer valid and would throw `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@href]` as of 1.3+

Answer (score 1):

It was for XPath selectors, of which support for has been dropped.